# Rendering one models 'edit form' in anothers 'index view'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables

I have two models, Teams and Players.  On the teams index page I have a list of players that aren't assigned to a team.  I'm trying to make a button so that I can click on one of the players with no team and have the 'edit form' of this player show up on the team index page.

This is my current team#index:

```
= link_to 'New Team', new_team_path
= link_to 'New Player', new_player_path

#teamLists
  - @teams.each do |team|
    .team
      .teamtitle
        .teamname
          = link_to truncate(team.name, length: 18), edit_team_path(team)
        .teammoney
          = number_to_currency(team.adjust_money, precision: 0)
      %table
        %tr.tableheading
          %th.namecolumn Player
          %th.poscolumn Pos
          %th.pricecolumn $
        -team.players.each do |player|
          %tr
            %td.namecolumn= player.name
            %td.poscolumn= player.position
            %td.pricecolumn= player.price
        -(1..(10-team.players.length)).each do |x|
          %tr
            %td ---
=render template: 'players/edit'
=render 'players/playerlist'
```

and this is my player#edit

```
%h1 Nominated Player
= render 'players/form'

= link_to 'Show', @player
= link_to 'Back', players_path
```

and the players/form

```
  <%= form_for(@player) do |f| %>
     <% if @player.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@player.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this player from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
        <% @player.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
         </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :position %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :position %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :price %><br />
      <%= f.number_field :price %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :team_id %><br />
      <%= f.select :team_id, Team.all.map { |team| [team.name, team.id] }, { :include_blank =>     true } %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

At the moment I get this error 'undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class' I think its because the form doesn't have access to @player which is defined in the players edit action.  Is there a way I can get this to work somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference any partial from another view page, and that's fine. However, like in your case, if that partial you require needs some instance variables (like `@player`) you'll have to either: A) declare it in the controller of Teams, or B) pass it in to the partial.

So for A), in your Teams controller for action `index`, just add `@player = Player.new` or whatever you need it to be.

For B), do:

render :partial => "my_partial", :locals => {:player => Player.new}

Comment: How about if I need @player = player.find(params[:id]) but on the index page there is no params?

Comment: If you have no way of knowing which player it is, you'll have to add that in somewhere. You have a list of players without teams, so when you make the link, you can add in something like a hidden field or a special ID on the link with the ID of the player. Then when you render the partial, grab the ID from the link, and use plan B) on my response to pass in `Player.find(the_id)`.